# Unique_ptr template error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have the following class with a vector of unique_ptrs:

```
class StatManager
{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IStat>> stats;
public:

    void setStat(const Stat<bool>& stat) {
        stats.emplace_back(stat.clone());
    }

    void setStat(const Stat<float>& stat) {
        stats.emplace_back(stat.clone());
    }

    void setStat(const Stat<int>& stat) {
        stats.emplace_back(stat.clone());
    }

    bool getStatValue(std::string name, float &value) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < stats.size(); x++)
        {
            if (stats.at(x)->getName() == name) {
                value = stats.at(x)->getAsFloat();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool getStatValue(std::string name, int &value) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < stats.size(); x++)
        {
            if (stats.at(x)->getName() == name) {
                value = stats.at(x)->getAsInt();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool getStatValue(std::string name, bool &value) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < stats.size(); x++)
        {
            if (stats.at(x)->getName() == name) {
                value = stats.at(x)->getAsBool();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

And the class that implements it:

```
class BaseItem
{
private:
    int id;
    std::string name;
public:
    BaseItem(int itemId, std::string itemName) : id(itemId), name(itemName) {}

    virtual int getID() = 0;
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
};


class Item : public BaseItem
{
private:
    StatManager statManager; //ERROR HERE trying to implement StatManager
public:
    Item(int id, std::string name);

    virtual int getID();
    virtual std::string getName();
};
```

I get the following error on visual studio 2013 while trying to make an attribute of StatManager:

```
Error   5   error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<IStat,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::
  unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)'
  : \xmemory0   593 1   GameTheory++
```

So in my main class i just try to create a local instance of StatManager and it work without any problem, for example:

```
float f = 0; 
StatManager manager; //Works flawless
manager.setStat(ItemStat("Durabilit", 100, ""));
manager.getStatValue("Durabilit", f);
```

So the problem happens only when trying to make StatManager as an attribute of any class... Is there anything i am missing, probably some move problem with the unique ptrs? I really dont know, thanks in advance.

**EDITED:**

Only place where i am using Item class is in the main method and trying to make a local instance of it:

```
Item item = Item(0, "Test");
```

Comment: You are probably trying to copy the `Item` somewhere. `unique_ptr`s can't be copied; they can only be moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not making StatManager an attribute of a class that's failing, it's trying to copy it.  Since it contains a vector of unique_ptrs, the whole class is non-copyable.  Presumably you're trying to copy it in some code you haven't posted.

To better diagnose the source of this problem, add this to your Item class:

```
Item(const Item&) = delete;
```

That way you'll get an error straight away when trying to copy it, rather than an error about unique_ptr buried within Item.

Edit: OK, so the code you posted just now is where the problem is:

```
Item item = Item(0, "Test");
```

This means "create an Item and copy it to `item`.  Instead, do this:

```
Item item(0, "Test");
```

This just creates an Item, and should work.

Comment: Cant believe i miss that my god must be the hour and messing with C# and VB, many thanks